# Friendly URL en ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación empleando ASP.NET Identity para el manejo del login. Dentro de la página Login.cshtml de ASP.NET identity quiero mandar otro parámetro que es el nombre de la compañía. El problema es que requiero que sea un friendly URL para el usuario.

Por ejemplo, ahorita funciona asi:

```
https://localhost:44311/Identity/Account/Login?company=EmpresaPrueba
```

Pero me gustaria que quedara:

```
https://localhost:44311/Identity/Account/Login/EmpresaPrueba
```

Alguna idea compañeros.

He probado con el atributo `Route` dentro del método

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string company=null)
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });



            services.AddDbContext<Data.DbContext>(options =>
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("Authentication")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddDefaultUI()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Data.DbContext>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {



            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar parte de tu `Startup.cs` por favor mi buen amigo? :D

Answer (score 1):

Mi solución fue esta... tal vez no es una forma muy sútil y fina de hacerlo, pero de momento funciona la redirección

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(
            o =>
            o.Conventions.AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention("Identity", "/Account/",
            model =>
            {
                foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
                {
                    var attributeRouteModel = selector.AttributeRouteModel;
                    attributeRouteModel.Order = -1;
                    if (attributeRouteModel.Template == "Identity/Account/Login")
                    {

                        attributeRouteModel.Template = "Account/Login/{company?}";


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        attributeRouteModel.Template =
                        attributeRouteModel.Template.Remove(0, "Identity".Length);
                    }

                }
            })
            ).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Comment: hey hermano :D Ya pasaron más de 24 horas, puedes marcar esta respuesta como aceptada, de tal manera que colaboras con la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas) y de paso obtengas algunos puntos para tu perfil :D un abrazo mi estimado lml

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con algo así:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "IdentityLoginRoute",
        template: "Account/Login/{company}",
        defaults : new{controller = "Account", action = "Login"
    });
}
```

Y en el controlador del login:

```
public IActionResult Login(string company)
{
   //Aqui va el código que tengas que tener :D
}
```

Comment: Ya intenté de esa forma y no funciona

Comment: me quiero volver chango, el código xD! <Feel Like Homero Simpson/> Ya bueno, será motivo de revisar a mayor detalle el tema de enrutamiento del Identity Server en ASPnet Core :D